# How do I manually impose the timestamp on a delta table version when merging?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I am continuously updating a Delta Table in Databricks using :

```
delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_path)
delta_table.alias("t").merge(
  df.alias("s"), ... # join condition
).whenMatchedUpdate(
  set=... # update columns
).whenNotMatchedInsert(
  values=... # insert columns
).execute()
```

Later, I would like to query different versions of the table using a timestamp. For example :

```
df = spark.read.format(
  "delta"
).option(
  "timestampAsOf",
  "2022-11-14 12:00:00",
).load(
  "s3://BUCKET/PREFIX/"
)
```

However, the timestamp here corresponds to the exact timestamp of the merge. If I happen to know a particular data set should correspond to a specific timestamp (if it's a dump from last week for example), is there any way to set that timestamp as the associated timestamp, rather than have it be set to whatever the time is when specifically executing the merge ? This would particularly useful if ever re-ingesting data for example, among other use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not aware of any option to do so. But there are other options which might be relevant.

1. Adding user defined metadata to the merge commit, here you could log your own timestamp. You can then view this with a `describe history`. From the databricks [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/custom-metadata.html#set-user-defined-commit-metadata):

```
df.write.format("delta") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("userMetadata", "overwritten-for-fixing-incorrect-data") \
  .save("/tmp/delta/people10m")
```

2. Simply have a log / table where you log the table name, version, and the desired timestamp.

A relevant heads up, by default the ability that you can time travel your delta table is only guaranteed up to 30 days. This can be configured using table properties `delta.logRetentionDuration` and `delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration`, the VACUUM operation (used for cleaning up parquet files of older version of the table) also plays a role here. See the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-vacuum.html).

Comment: In addition to @ScootCork call out, wondering if you could create a batch queue table which contains a Batch ID for each batch and then you can do the associated dates as you see fit?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could certainly match batch IDs with dates in a separate table myself, but I just supposed there would be native support for this. I would imagine that very rarely if ever is the end user interested in the technical date of ingestion as opposed to a functional record date, so I assumed rather hopefully this could be done out of the box.

Comment: Could I just ask how exactly the `userMetadata` option would look for fixing a specific datetime ? And would this be the datetime used by `timestampAsOf` or would it just show up in `describe history` and nothing more ?

Comment: The `userMetadata` is just for reference, it has no effect on `timestampAsOf`. Manually specifying commit timestamps raises concerns, what happens if you specify something before the latest commit? or in the future? In multi user scenarios, people would want to reproduce the exact output of a query they ran based on the timestamp and not suddenly get something else. This is simply not intended for functional usecases as you describe, you could design the table as a SCD type 2 though?

Comment: In case of inconsistencies I would expect it to fail. I understand there are ambiguities to be resolved in doing so, but personally I would find whatever constraints to come with that to have been useful. For example simply imposing that manual timestamps must increase monotonously solves most of that and is a minor (and perfectly reasonable) constraint. Question of use cases I suppose.

Comment: The table is an SCD type 2. My question is simply about being able to traverse it using a manually set functional timestamp rather than the technical ingestion timestamp.